# JavaScript - improve the construction of the dynamic object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, if-statement

I have this script that builds an object:

```
console.log(solution([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2]))


function solution(inputArray) {
  let arrMap = [] 

  for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) { 
      var repeated = false;
      var e = arrMap.find(s => s.element == inputArray[i])
      
      if(e){        
        repeated = true;
        e.repeated = true;      
        e.firstPosition = e.position
        e.lastPosition = i           
        delete e['position'];
      }
      
      arrMap.push({
        element : inputArray[i],
        position: i,       
        repeated: repeated
      })
    } 

  return arrMap
}
```

This is the object that the script builds:

```
[
  { element: 2, repeated: true, firstPosition: 0, lastPosition: 5 },
  { element: 1, position: 1, repeated: false },
  { element: 3, repeated: true, firstPosition: 2, lastPosition: 4 },
  { element: 5, position: 3, repeated: false },
  { element: 3, position: 4, repeated: true },
  { element: 2, position: 5, repeated: true }
]
```

I simply want to make a change to the return by deleting the remaining lines of the items that are repeated, in this case, items 2 and 3. As shown below:

```
[
   { element: 2, repeated: true, firstPosition: 0, lastPosition: 5 },
   { element: 1, position: 1, repeated: false },
   { element: 3, repeated: true, firstPosition: 2, lastPosition: 4 },
   { element: 5, position: 3, repeated: false },
   { element: 3, position: 4, repeated: true }, //<---- DUPLICATED! DELETE THIS LINE
   { element: 2, position: 5, repeated: true } //<---- DUPLICATED! DELETE THIS LINE
]
```

The result should be as shown below:

```
 [
   { element: 2, repeated: true, firstPosition: 0, lastPosition: 5 },
   { element: 1, position: 1, repeated: false },
   { element: 3, repeated: true, firstPosition: 2, lastPosition: 4 },
   { element: 5, position: 3, repeated: false },     
 ]
```

Comment: Just add an `else` before `arrMap.push` so the push only happens when there are no repeats found.  Your code currently always tries to add a new element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing to an intermediate object makes it easier (and cheaper, performance-wise) to check if an element has already been added to the result:

```js
const solution = (a) => Object.values(a.reduce((a, v, i) => {
  if (a[v]) {
    a[v].repeated = true;
    a[v].firstPosition = a[v].firstPosition || a[v].position;
    a[v].lastPosition = i;
    
    delete a[v].position;
  } else {
    a[v] = {
      element: v,
      repeated: false,
      position: i
    };
  }
  
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(solution([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved the code according the idea of the user 120242 and now it is working well and reaching the expected result!

```
function solution(inputArray) {
  let arrMap = []

  for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {   
    var e = arrMap.find(s => s.element == inputArray[i])

    if (e) {
      e.repeated = true;
      e.firstPosition = e.position
      e.lastPosition = i
      delete e['position'];
    } else {
      arrMap.push({
        repeated: false,
        element: inputArray[i],
        position: i,
        repeated: repeated
      })
    }
  }

  return arrMap
}
```